# Почему при вызове setPivot() не учитывается угол наклона (rotate)?

Tags: java, android, pivot, android-view, gestures

Есть две `view`, одна вложена в другую. На внешней установлен слушатель жестов (`OnTouchListener`), внутренняя подвергается трансформациям `scale`, `rotate` и `translate`. При жестах `rotate` и `pinch to zoom` мне необходимо устанавливать точку `pivot`. Я это делаю так:

```
private void setPivot(float focusX, float focusY) {
  PointF newPivot = new PointF(
    (focusX - scroll.x + pivot.x * (scale.x - 1)) / scale.x,
    (focusY - scroll.y + pivot.y * (scale.y - 1)) / scale.y
  );

  PointF newScroll = new PointF(
    scroll.x - (pivot.x - newPivot.x) * (scale.x - 1),
    scroll.y - (pivot.y - newPivot.y) * (scale.y - 1)
  );

  pivot = newPivot;
  contentView.setPivotX(pivot.x);
  contentView.setPivotY(pivot.y);

  scroll = newScroll;
  contentView.setTranslationX(scroll.x);
  contentView.setTranslationY(scroll.y);
}
```

Точка `focus` берется с внешней `view` вот так:

```
private PointF getCenter(MotionEvent event) {
  int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
  int index = event.getActionIndex();

  float sumX = 0;
  float sumY = 0;
  int num = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP && index == i) {
      continue;
    }

    sumX += event.getX(i);
    sumY += event.getY(i);
    num++;
  }

  return new PointF(sumX / num, sumY / num);
}
```

Проблема в том, что в `setPivot()` не учитывается `rotate` (угол наклона внутренней `view`). Без трансформаций `rotate` все работает отлично, но с трансформацией наклона при повторных вызовах `setPivot()` происходит скачок внутренней `view`.

**Вопрос:** Каким образом правильно рассичитать `pivot` с учетом `rotate`?

**UPD Увы, награду отдать некому, но я пока оставлю этот вопрос в надежде что кто-то додумается. Или чуть попозже, когда вернусь к этой проблеме, то опубликую получившееся решение.**

Comment: Вы не сказали самого главного - в какое место View она должна быть установлена и зачем её пересчитывать.

Comment: Точка pivot устанавливается в произвольное место view в зависимости от того, где будет сделан жест pinch to zoom или rotate. Pivot - это средняя точка между двумя пальцами, которыми делается жест. Пересчитывается она потому, что три жеста: pan, pinch и rotate выполняются одновременно и человек может перетаскивать contentView одновременно крутя и переворачивая его.